# pandas. cambiar datos de columna en base a un criterio dado por un diccionario que hay que recorrer

Tags: python, pandas, bucles, diccionarios

gracias de antemano por la ayuda para salir de este atasco mental.

Estoy trabajando con un df del que necesito sustituir los valores de provincia de la columna `df['provincia']` por su correspondiente comunidad autónoma.

Ejemplo:

`df['provincia']=='ALICANTE'` que sea sustituido por `'CCAA Com. Valenciana'`.

Para ello tengo un diccionario:

```
d_com={'CCAA Com. Valenciana':['ALICANTE','CASTELLON','VALENCIA'], 'CCAA Madrid':['MADRID']}
```

He probado:

1.

```
comunidades=di_com.keys()

provincias=di_com.values()

for provincia in provincias:

    for i in range(0,len(provincia)):

        df.loc[df['provincia']==provincia[i],'provincia']='di_com.keys'

#'di_com.keys' debería ser la key de provincia[i], pero no sé recuperarla
```

2. 

```
for i,j in enumerate(di_com.items()):

    for i in j:

        df.loc[df['provincia']==dicc_com[j][i],'provincia']=dicc_com[j]


#Da error
```

3. 

```
for i, comu in enumerate(di_com):

    df['provincia'].replace([dicc_com[word][i]],word,inplace=True)


#también error: 'list index out of range'
```

Me cuesta recorrer diccionarios y más si el valor es una lista.

¿Alguna sugerencia que me permita avanzar?. ¡GRACIAS!

Comment: Buen día, ¿Cualquiera de las siguientes palabras `'ALICANTE','CASTELLON','VALENCIA'` debe sustituirse por `'CCAA Com. Valenciana'`? Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega algunas filas de los datos que tienes, hay muchos usuarios (Me incluyo) que no conocemos las provincias y comunidades autónomas de España, deberías ser más específico con lo que debería hacer el código. Te recomiendo leer [ask] y realizar el [tour].

Comment: Buenos días. Hacer un  ejemplo sencillo y genérico ha sido mi intención. Tengo el diccionario y columna indicadas. He de localizando en la columna el dato que coincida con alguna value del diccionario y sustituirlo por la key asociada.

Comment: Si, eso lo entiendo, pero por ejemplo tienes una lista para `'CCAA Com. Valenciana'` ¿Eso quiere decir que cualquiera de las 3 palabras debe ser sustituida por `'CCAA Com. Valenciana'`?

Comment: Sí, exacto. Si encuentro 'ALICANTE', o 'CASTELLON' o 'VALENCIA' en la columna, se debe sustituir por 'CCAA Com. Valenciana'.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

**Nota:** Al utilizar pandas es recomendable no utilizar ciclos (Por ejemplo `for`) para iterar en los elementos, hay métodos optimizados que trabajan con el dataset rápida y eficientemente. En la mayoría de los casos, si lo que quieres hacer crees que se puede hacer con un for entonces es el camino incorrecto (O el que va a tardar más y tener mayor impacto al procesador). En esos casos, si no hay un método directo que realice la tarea entonces apply podría ser una buena opción, como último recurso sería utilizar ciclos.

La forma más fácil para realizar lo que buscas es utilizar [`pandas.DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) con un diccionario (Casi lo logras) pero el diccionario debe tener como llaves las palabras que buscas y como valores las palabras que se utilizarán para reemplazar.

Es decir, algo así:

```
diccionario = {'ALICANTE': 'CCAA Com. Valenciana', 'CASTELLÓN': 'CCAA Com. Valenciana', 'VALENCIA': 'CCAA Com. Valenciana', 'MADRID': 'CCAA Madrid'}
```

Ahora, en tu pregunta no mencionas si las palabras siempre van a estar en mayúsculas o si va a haber combinaciones con mayúsculas y minúsculas, por ejemplo así:

```
    provincia
0   ALICANTE
1   CASTELLÓN
2   VALENCIA
3   Alicante
4   Castellón
5   Valencia
6   Madrid
7   MADRID
```

**Nota adicional:** Las vocales con tilde van acentuadas aunque sean mayúsculas.

Entonces si hay combinaciones en filas con valores únicamente en mayúsculas o si tienen mayúsculas y minúsculas es mejor utilizar un `regex` (Del inglés `Regular Expression`). Para considerar valores sin distinción de mayúsculas y minúsculas podemos utilizar el `regex` `(?i)` antes de las palabras, por ejemplo:

```
diccionario = {'(?i)ALICANTE': 'CCAA Com. Valenciana', '(?i)CASTELLÓN': 'CCAA Com. Valenciana', '(?i)VALENCIA': 'CCAA Com. Valenciana', '(?i)MADRID': 'CCAA Madrid'}
```

Esto va a ocasionar que las palabras coincidan sin importar si son solo mayúsculas, minúsculas o alguna combinación de ambas.

Ejemplo completo (Los datos los puse en un archivo "sample2.csv"):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample2.csv')
diccionario = {'(?i)ALICANTE': 'CCAA Com. Valenciana', '(?i)CASTELLÓN': 'CCAA Com. Valenciana', '(?i)VALENCIA': 'CCAA Com. Valenciana', '(?i)MADRID': 'CCAA Madrid'}
df = df.replace({'provincia': diccionario}, regex=True)
```

Al imprimir `df` obtenemos el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
    provincia
0   CCAA Com. Valenciana
1   CCAA Com. Valenciana
2   CCAA Com. Valenciana
3   CCAA Com. Valenciana
4   CCAA Com. Valenciana
5   CCAA Com. Valenciana
6   CCAA Madrid
7   CCAA Madrid
```

Comment: gracias por la explicativa y detallada respuesta. 
Pensé que era posible entrar en las values de un diccionario , sean elementos únicos o conjunto de elementos,  y devolver su key. No quería cambiar el diccionario porque es bastante largo, lo empleo más veces y me resulta complejo hacerlo.
Pero si no encuentro opción, lo haré...lo que me lleva a preguntar si hay algún método automatizado para poner a cada value individual su key y rehacer el diccionario.

Answer (score 0):

Conseguí encontrar una solución sin modificar el diccionario. La comparto por si es utilidad:

```
dict={'com_madrid':['madrid'],
     'com_valencia':['valencia','alicante','castellón']}
lista_llaves=list(dict.keys())
lista_valores=list(dict.values())

for i,k in enumerate(lista_valores):
    for j in k:
        df1.loc[df1['Comunidad']==j,'Comunidad']=lista_llaves[i]
```